# Javascript: How do I get the index of a certain order of values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to create a markov chain. Right now, I need to get the index of some values in an array. Is there any way that is possible?

I tried to use indexOf, but that only supports one argument.

Let's assume there is a function named INDEX that does what I need.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1];
INDEX(arr, [1, 2]) // returns 0, because 1, 2 is in the first index in the array.
INDEX(arr, [3, 4, 3]) // returns 2, because 3, 4, 3 starts at the third index.
INDEX(arr, [2, 3]) // returns 1, because there are two 2, 3s, so it returns the first.
INDEX(arr, [5, 6]) // returns -1, because it is not in the array.
INDEX(arr, [1, 4]) // even though these values are in the array, they aren't in the order, so returns -1
```

Comment: how large can your array be?

Comment: Could you treat it like a string and use substr?

Comment: @pavanskipo Around 2 - 12 in length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.findIndex`, and check whether `every` one of the array items follows the current index:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1];

const INDEX = (arr, toFind) => arr.findIndex(
  (_, baseI, arr) => toFind.every((item, i) => arr[baseI + i] === item)
);

console.log(
  INDEX(arr, [1, 2]), // returns 0, because 1, 2 is in the first index in the array.
  INDEX(arr, [3, 4, 3]), // returns 2, because 3, 4, 3 starts at the third index.
  INDEX(arr, [2, 3]), // returns 1, because there are two 2, 3s, so it returns the first.
  INDEX(arr, [5, 6]), // returns -1, because it is not in the array.
  INDEX(arr, [1, 4]) // even though these values are in the array, they aren't in the order, so returns -1
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I needed! My life purpose is fulfilled now.

Comment: @WilliamWill Please accept the answer.. if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and neat approach is to deal with strings in this case.

So you can convert both the arrays to strings and use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
const INDEX = (arr, toFind) => arr.join('').indexOf(toFind.join(''))
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1]

const INDEX = (arr, toFind) => arr.join('').indexOf(toFind.join(''))

console.log(
  INDEX(arr, [1, 2]),
  INDEX(arr, [3, 4, 3]),
  INDEX(arr, [2, 3]),
  INDEX(arr, [5, 6]),
  INDEX(arr, [1, 4])
)
```

Comment: This will not be reliable if the array items are outside the single digits, or if they're decimal, or if they're non-numbers